# How to pass tuple as argument to django function

Tags: django, django-views, tuples

I want to pass tuple to this function but i am getting error

```
mytuple = [('id', 'name','author')]
mybooks = Book.objects.values_list(mytuple)
```

error is

```
'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: You're not passing a tuple to your function but a list.

Comment: Actually i was using tuple but when i get error i put [] to test

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use:

```
mytuple = ('id', 'name', 'author')
mybooks = Book.objects.values_list(*mytuple)
```

Comment: It works because he used the * before the tuple name which expands it.

Comment: In Python, calling `foo(*list)` is roughy equivalent to calling `foo(list[0], list[1], …, list[len(list)-1])`.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-and-do-for-python-parameters